# Android Intent is called to fast

Tags: android, android-intent

Looking to understand why my intent service is not beening called.

i'm basically caling my intent in this way;

```
JSONArray cmds = o.getJSONArray("cmds");
for(int i = 0; i<cmds.length(); i++){
   JSONObject jo = cmds.getJSONObject(i);
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.protectoria.www.pas","com.example.www.pas.CommandProcessor"));
   intent.putExtra("cmd", jo.toString());
   this.startService(intent);
}
```

In my test code the `JSONArray` contains 9 elements so in a tight loop 9 intents are being started. The `CommandProcessor.onHandleIntent` misses out on a couple of these. Looks like it's a timing issue because if I put a breakpoint in the `onHandleIntent` all 9 are being received.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try sending one intent with multiple commands (cmd's):

```
JSONArray cmds = o.getJSONArray("cmds");
// create an arraylist to hold the commands
ArrayList<String> cmds = new ArrayList<String>();
// create the intent outside of the loop
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.protectoria.www.pas", "com.example.www.pas.CommandProcessor"));
for (int i = 0; i<cmds.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jo = cmds.getJSONObject(i);
    // add command to the list
    cmds.add(jo.toString());
}
// loop is done, add the cmds list (serializable) to the intent and start
intent.putExtra("cmds", cmds);
this.startService(intent);
```

Then in the handleIntent pick up the `cmds` out of the intent and run them in a loop there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use IntentService, as it is designed for handling asynchronous tasks. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html